# Dax measure- sum of percent of total by group with condition

Tags: dax

For simplicity sake, I have the following dummy data:

```
id  val
1   5
1   30
1   50
1   15
2   120
2   60
2   10
2   10
```

My desired output is the following:

```
id  SUM_GT_10%
1   95%
2   90%
```

SUM_GT_10% can be obtained by the following steps:

1. Calculate the sum of val for each id
2. Divide val by 1
3. sum of 2 if 2 > 10%

using the example data, the sum of val is 100 for id 1 and 200 for id 2, so we would obtain the following additional columns:

```
id  val   1      2   
1   5     100    5%
1   30    100    30%
1   50    100    50% 
1   15    100    15%
2   120   200    60%
2   60    200    30%
2   10    200    5%
2   10    200    5%
```

And our final output (step 3) would be sum of 2 where 2> 10%:

```
id   SUM_GT_10%
1    95%
2    90%
```

I don't care about the intermediate columns, just the final output, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James, you might want to create a temporary table in your measure and then sum its results:

```
tbl_SumVAL = 
    var ThisId = MAX(tbl_VAL[id])
    var temp = 
        FILTER(
            SELECTCOLUMNS(tbl_VAL, "id", tbl_VAL[id], "GT%", 
                tbl_VAL[val] / SUMX(FILTER(tbl_VAL, tbl_VAL[id] = ThisId), tbl_VAL[val])), 
            [GT%] > 0.1
        )
    return
        SUMX(temp, [GT%])
```

The temp table is basically recreating two steps that you have described (divide "original" value by the sum of all values for each ID), and then leaving only those values that are greater than 0.1. Note that if your id is not a number, then you'd need to replace `MAX(tbl_VAL[id])` with `SELECTEDVALUE(tbl_VAL[id])`.

The final result looks like that -

[image]

Also, make sure to set your `id` field to "Not Summarize", in case `id` is a number -

[image]